# jquery $.grep in deferred object returns Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, grep, each, jquery-deferred

I am having a problem trying to get a value using $.grep

I send off a GET request to a url to bring back loads of dates and values as JSON.

in the callback function I then get dates and values from a JSON file and assign the result to a variable using a deferred object.

Once the ajax request has completed, I loop through the original response and then I use $.grep to filter the json variable to get the correct value .

If I console.log the result of the $.grep, I get the correct value dumped out however I get the following error.

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

How can I get the value from $.grep?

```
var history;

$.getJSON(window.website_url + 'history', function(response) {

    var series = { 
        name: 'Price Index History', 
        data: []
    };

    var deferreds = [];

    if($('#currency').val() === 'GBP') {

        deferreds.push(
            $.ajax({
                url: window.website_url = 'exchange-rate',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    history = data;
                }
            })
        );

        $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {

            $.each(response, function(i, item) {

                var date = new Date(item[0]),
                    day;

                if((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10) {
                    day = date.getFullYear() + '-' + '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
                }
                else {
                    day = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
                }

                var result = $.grep(history, function(e) { return e.date == day; });

                var test = result[0].value;

                series.data.push([item[0], Number(parseFloat(item[1] * result[0].value).toFixed(1))]);
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            series.data.push([item[0], item[1]]);
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

```
Here is the json returned the ajax request
[
    {
        "date":"2018-01-30",
        "value":0.706419
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-01-31",
        "value":0.70417
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-02-01",
        "value":0.70095
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-02-02",
        "value":0.70808
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-02-03",
        "value":0.70808
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-02-04",
        "value":0.70871},
    {
        "date":"2018-02-05",
        "value":0.717141
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-02-06",
        "value":0.71645
    },
    {
        "date":"2018-02-07",
        "value":0.716369
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please show the results of your ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem...

For days of the month such as 01 - 09, `getDate()` will return a single digit (i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc).

For the date `2018-02-06` you are comparing `2018-02-06` with `2018-01-6`

Use a function like this to replace `6` with `06`

```
function day_of_month(d) { 
    return (d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getDate();
}
```

such as

```
day = date.getFullYear() + '-' + '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + day_of_month(getDate());
```